# Sending POST Data via PHP CURL Not Working

Tags: php, curl

Using the code below, I'm unable to send any POST data. The page that is supposed to receive it, isn't receiving it for some reason..

```
$url = "http://www.somesite.com/curl_test_page.php";

$employee_id = 5;
$post_fields = "employee_id=" . $employee_id;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);     

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

On the curl_test_page.php, the code is as follows:

```
$employee_id = $_POST['employee_id'];
echo $employee_id;
```

When I run the CURL script, it displays an empty page.

Answer (score 4):

1. You are not using *curl_init*
2. Is recomended force the enctype with *CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER*
3. I recomend you use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function

Example:

```
$url = "http://www.somesite.com/curl_test_page.php";

$employee_id = 5;

$post_fields = Array(
    employee_id => $employee_id
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_fields));     

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing any output. Try adding

```
<?php
echo $result;
?>
```